# evaluate cell in 2d array using spring expression language

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

In a spring mvc application, I have a jsp which needs to iterate through two collections who both share the same index, `i`.  The `blocks` List contains time values.  The `filledblocks` array is a 2d array whose first element in each row is the block index `i`.  For each value of `i`, the jsp needs to check the value of the second element in the row, and determine which output to send to the user depending on whether the second elements value is 0 or not 0.

Here is the line of code that is triggering the error:

```
<spring:eval expression="filledblocks[i][1]!=0" var="appointment" />
```

Here is the exception being thrown:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:  
No converter found capable of converting from type  
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status  
to type java.lang.Integer
```

Here is the jsp code in which the above line resides:

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Time Slots</th>
                        <th>Appointments</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>    
                <c:forEach var="block" items="${calendar.blocks}" varStatus="i">
                    <spring:eval expression="calendar.getBlockMillis(block)" var="dateTime"/>
                    <tr class="${i.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : ''}">
                        <td width="100px" class="block">
                            <joda:format value="${block}" style="-S" />
                        </td>
                            <spring:eval expression="filledblocks[i][1]!=0" var="appointment" />
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${appointment == true}">
                                    <td class="filled" data-dateTime="<c:out value="${dateTime}" />" >
                                        <a href="${testLink}" style="display:block;">&nbsp;There is an appointment.</a>
                                    <c:url var="testLink" value="/">
                                        <c:param name="somevarname" value="test" />
                                    </c:url>
                                    </td>
                           </c:when>
                           <c:otherwise>
                               <c:url var="testLink" value="/">
                                   <c:param name="somevarname" value="test" />
                               </c:url>
                               <td class="open" data-dateTime="<c:out value="${dateTime}" />" >
                                   <a href="${testLink}" style="display:block;">No Appointment</a>
                               </td>
                           </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Feb 14, 2014 10:49:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status to type java.lang.Integer
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:276)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:172)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.convertValue(ExpressionState.java:142)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Indexer.getValueRef(Indexer.java:418)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Indexer.getValueInternal(Indexer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpNE.getValueInternal(OpNE.java:37)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpNE.getValueInternal(OpNE.java:29)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.doEndTag(EvalTag.java:121)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005feval_005f2(calendar_jsp.java:652)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(calendar_jsp.java:557)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspService(calendar_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Feb 14, 2014 10:49:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [KnowledgeManager] in context with path [/KnowledgeManager] threw exception [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:(pos 12): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status to java.lang.Integer] with root cause
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status to type java.lang.Integer
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:276)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:172)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.convertValue(ExpressionState.java:142)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Indexer.getValueRef(Indexer.java:418)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Indexer.getValueInternal(Indexer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpNE.getValueInternal(OpNE.java:37)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpNE.getValueInternal(OpNE.java:29)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.doEndTag(EvalTag.java:121)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005feval_005f2(calendar_jsp.java:652)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(calendar_jsp.java:557)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspService(calendar_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying a funky class cast, which won't work. Use this instead:

```
<spring:eval expression="filledblocks[i.index][1]!=0" var="appointment" />
```

Comment: Seems you deleted the question just as I was replying to you. :) Adding index + 1 to a field, then looping vs. that tends to get you those IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

Comment: Nah, don't worry about it. Minor inconvenience. Although what you can also do is write an answer yourself, if it's a problem you think someone else may run into.

Comment: I have another related question. Are you willing to help me solve it?  Here is the link to the new posting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002272/entity-relationship-not-populating-properly